# Error ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49) on Multi-Master

Tags: openldap

The error that appears is this:

```
   Dec 30 18:07:24 openldap03 slapd[16460]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://openldap02 DN="cn=config" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
    Dec 30 18:07:24 openldap03 slapd[16460]: do_syncrepl: rid=002 rc 49 retrying (1 retries left)
    Dec 30 18:07:24 openldap03 slapd[16460]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://openldap01 DN="cn=config" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
    Dec 30 18:07:24 openldap03 slapd[16460]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc 49 retrying (1 retries left)
```

...

```
    Dec 30 18:09:54 openldap03 slapd[16460]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://openldap02 DN="cn=ldapadm,dc=domain,dc=local" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
    Dec 30 18:09:54 openldap03 slapd[16460]: do_syncrepl: rid=005 rc 49 retrying (1 retries left)
    Dec 30 18:09:54 openldap03 slapd[16460]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://openldap01 DN="cn=ldapadm,dc=domain,dc=local" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)
    Dec 30 18:09:54 openldap03 slapd[16460]: do_syncrepl: rid=004 rc 49 retrying (1 retries left)
```

Connection is fine:

```
[root@openldap03 ~]# telnet openldap01 389
Trying 172.16.11.203...
Connected to openldap01.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

[root@openldap03 ~]# telnet openldap02 389
Trying 172.16.11.205...
Connected to openldap02.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
```

I can add the configuration if they ask me what command to execute
How can I troubleshoot this error?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The return code 49 stands for "Invalid credential". You do not have connectivity problem, but the credential you set are not the right one.